# understanding tsung report: clarification required between Page and Session Main statistics

Tags: tsung

Here is the session i am using:

```
<sessions> 
<session type="ts_http" name="Test" probability="100">
<for var="i" to="1" from="1"> 
<request subst="true"> 
<http version="1.1" contents="%%autoupload:readdata%%" method="POST" url="/UploadFile"> 
<http_header name="key" value="testkey"/> 
<http_header name="Filename" value="test.zip"/>
</http> 
</request> 
</for> 
</session>
```

The session has got only one post request. so the mean page response time and mean request response time are same as expected, in the tsung report.
but i was expecting the mean for user session also to be nearly same with deviation of only connection time.

below is snap of tsung report:

```
Name highest-10sec-mean lowest-10sec-mean   Highest-Rate    Mean-Rate   Mean    Count

connect  1.55 sec       4.11 msec            0.5 / sec     0.24 / sec   0.50 sec  47 

page    26.35 sec       2.50 sec             0.9 / sec     0.24 / sec   12.83 sec 43 

request 26.35 sec       2.50 sec             0.9 / sec    0.24 / sec    12.83 sec 43 

session 30.83 sec       6.91 sec             0.9 / sec    0.25 / sec    17.73 sec 44
```

Wanted to understand what is it that getting added in the session mean time, such that the session time is higher than page/request time.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC `page` means a consecutive sequence of requests within a session, without thinktimes/waits. Depending on the load you are configuring, `session` also includes work required to get the session started. As starting new sessions is not free, you could try to launch 1/10th users and let each user to 10 requests. `page` and `session` should be almost identical then.

It's a bit strange though, that you see almost 5 sec difference on the mean values. Could you provide more details on your environment? (os/tsung/erlang versions, entire configuration, ...)